# How to combine dependent probabilities?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume there are 3 types of events: E1, E2 and E3.

Probability that E3 happens if E1 happened is P1.
Probability that E3 happens if E2 happened is P2.

Let's assume E1 and E2 are independent events.

What's the probability of E3 if both E1 and E2 happened?

Comment: Check this out for reference: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/how-can-i-calculate-the-conditional-probability-of-several-events

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $\Pr(E_1),\Pr(E_2)>0$, the probability you are interested in (lets cal it $P_3$) is
$$
P_3:=
\Pr(E_3 \mid E_1 \cap E_2)
=\frac{\Pr(E_3 \cap E_1 \cap E_2)}{\Pr(E_1 \cap E_2)}
=\frac{\Pr((E_3 \cap E_1) \cap (E_3 \cap E_2))}{\Pr(E_1) \Pr(E_2)}.
$$
Now, if you only knew that $(E_3 \cap E_1)$ and $(E_3 \cap E_2)$ were independent, then you would have that
$$P_3
=\frac{\Pr(E_3 \cap E_1)}{\Pr(E_1)} \cdot \frac{ \Pr(E_3 \cap E_2)}{\Pr(E_2)}
= P_1 \cdot P_2.$$

**But this is not the case.** You do not have enough information to determine $P_3$. Indeed, lets look at two examples that will provide a proof of this claim:

1. Say you roll a fair die with $6$ sides $\{1,2,\dots,6\}$, and define
   $$\begin{align*}
   E_1 &= \{2,4,6\}\\
   E_2 &= \{1,2\}\\
   E_3 &= \{2\}
   \end{align*}
   $$
   so that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are independent, $P_1=\frac{1}{3}$, $P_2=\frac{1}{2}$. Then
   $$P_3
   =\frac{|E_3 \cap E_1 \cap E_2|}{|E_1 \cap E_2|}
   =1.$$
2. Say you roll a fair die with $12$ sides $\{1,2,\dots,12\}$, and define
   $$\begin{align*}
   E_1 &= \{2,4,6,8,10,12\}\\
   E_2 &= \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\\
   E_3 &= \{1,2,4\}
   \end{align*}
   $$
   so that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are independent, $P_1=\frac{1}{3}$, $P_2=\frac{1}{2}$. Then, while the values of $P_1$ and $P_2$ are the same as in the previous example, the value of $P_3$ is different:
   $$P_3
   =\frac{|E_3 \cap E_1 \cap E_2|}{|E_1 \cap E_2|}
   =\frac{2}{3}.
   $$